# How to pass ID from Laravel Blade view to Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

**Question** I am trying to pass an `$id` from blade view `@foreach` loop to a `Model` so that I could return all the cards associated with this specific `page`.

- Kanban has many Pages, Columns, Cards
- Page  and has many Cards
- Column  and has many Cards

The idea being, that you can click on all tasks and it would go to
`http://kanban.test/team/kanban/1/show-all` and show all tasks.

When you click trough the `pages` those would be like tag filters and take you to
`http://kanban.test/team/kanban/1/1/show`

[image]

When I manually set the `page id = 1` it does work. When I try and pass the ID, it doesn't give any errors, but nothing shows up.

**Manually Setting ID**

```
// Column.php Model
public function tasksOnPage(){
        return $this->cards()->where('page_id',1);
    }

// Blade View
@foreach ($kanban->columns as $column )

   @foreach ($column->tasksOnPage as $card)
      @include('kanbans.show-card') 
   @endforeach

@endforeach
```

**Trying to pass the id**

When I do `{{$page->id}}` it does show the correct id of `1` inside each column.

```
// Column.php Model
public function tasksOnPage($id){
        return $this->cards()->where('page_id',$id);
    }

// Blade View
@foreach ($kanban->columns as $column )

   @foreach ($column->tasksOnPage($page->id) as $card)
       @include('kanbans.show-card') 
   @endforeach

@endforeach
```

If I was getting some errors, that would be helpful >.< . Any suggestions on how I could debug this to find what could possibly be the issue? Since the page loads fine, and there is no errors?

Comment: You can change/update/set the value via JavaScript and pull the data via Ajax, may I know your current process ?

Comment: I am not using Vue but just vanilla laravel here.

Comment: Okay, I am not talking about Vue, if you wish to pass data from view/blade to controller and get data corresponding the value you have to perform an HTTP request, you can perform the request via regular php/Ajax, in your case Ajax will be a great option, you can use Vue if you wish can take a look at jQuery it's easy but old

Comment: Aah thanks, will look into that :) Still a newbie at this >.< haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to make this into a livewire component, and I was able to pass the ID this way.

```
@foreach ($kanbans as $kanban )
   @livewire('kanbans.show-sidebar-kanban', ['kanban'=>$kanban], key($kanban->id))
@endforeach
```

This video on nesting helped quite a bit :)

For anyone that might be stuck on this as well

https://laravel-livewire.com/screencasts/nesting

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
// Blade View
@foreach ($kanban->columns as $column )

   @foreach ($column->cards()->where('page_id', $page->id) as $card)
       @include('kanbans.show-card') 
   @endforeach

@endforeach
```